# C string modification

Tags: c, string

I came across a confused problem when I program in C

when i use `oldPacket.filename = "fallout.jpg"` //i have a file called fallout.jpg,and a struct called oldPakcet with an char* type filename

The program ran very well

Now, I decide to let user to in put the filename and also check the existence of the file. I wrote the following function:

```
bool Searchfile(packet* ptr) {
    char userinput[100];
    fgets(userinput, sizeof (userinput), stdin); //non terminated input by fgets
    userinput[strcspn(userinput, "\n")] = 0;
    //printf("%d\n",strlen(userinput));
    ptr->filename = userinput + 4;//i skip the first 4 char since the correnct format is ftp <filename>
    printf("%s\n",ptr->filename);
    printf("%d\n",strlen(ptr->filename));
    ptr->filename[strlen(ptr->filename)] = '\0';
    if (access(ptr->filename, F_OK) != -1) {
        printf("exist\n");
        return false;
    } else {
        //printf("does not exist\n");
        return true;
    }
}
```

I call this function by

```
while (Searchfile(&oldPacket)){
    printf("Please input the file name in the format: ftp <file name> \n");
}
```

However the program is no longer working and it shows seg fault at

```
int filesize;
    fp = fopen(oldPacket.filename, "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);//here is the seg fault
```

Anyone have some idea why this happen ?

I already printf each char of the filename and it looks correct....

Thanks in advance

Comment: You return a pointer to a variable on stack that goes out of scope.

Comment: Also looking at the location of the seg fault, you may be interested in the value of "fp".

Answer (score 2):

You let `ptr->filename` point to an address of local variable `userinput`, and accessing this value once `userinput` has gone out of scope is undefined behaviour.

The reason for the segfault is probably that the value of `filename`, when accessed outside of `Searchfile`, may be garbage, such that the file will not be opened. The subsequent `fseek` will then be called with a `NULL`-value for `fp`...

A simple solution to overcome this would be to write `static char userinput[100];`, at least when you are not working in a multithreaded environment. Otherwise you'd have to reserve memory for `ptr->filename` and copy contents of `userinput`.